# Can we use multiple ordinal endogeneous variables in SEM model using lavaan?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I have three endogenous variables each measured using 5-point likert scale ranging from Strongly Agree to Strongly Disagree. I want to use SEM for my analysis using Lavaan. All the examples I have come across so far in the tutorials have used only 1 categorical endogeneous variable. Therefore, I would like to know if it is okay to use multiple ordinal endogenous variables in SEM model using lavaan and is there any tutorial available that can be useful to me.

Comment: Yes. Just put more than one in. Many models have multiple ordinal endogenous variables (if you don't, there's much less reason to use lavaan).

Comment: I see you are new, so don't take this as aggressive.  But in the future, I would advise trying something before asking whether you can do it.  FYI, there is an example of a categorical CFA in the `?lavTables` help page